# How to calculate collection view cell height using cell defined in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uikit

I've got a storyboard with a view controller with a collection view in it. In the collection view there is one type of reusable cell: a custom subclass of UIView with a couple of labels in it, connected to IBOutlets and laid out using autolayout.

To calculate the layout of the collection view, I want to instantiate the cell programatically so I can assign text to the labels and measure the height of a cell for a given width.

Is it possible to instantiate just that custom cell programatically from the view controller?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. I usually create a property for my cell, and instantiate it in viewDidLoad (using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:), then use that cell for doing size calculations in collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RDCell" forIndexPath:nil];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I had tried this in the method that calculates cell height, but ended up with an infinite cycle.